# Nginx configuration for one more project which are running on Tomcat7

Tags: spring, nginx, tomcat7

I have two projects which are running on Tomcat7. 
http://localhost:8080/mysite1 and http://localhost:8080/mysite2

mysite1.com and mysite2.com should work on one server.

Example nginx configuration.

```
server {
      server_name mysite1.com;
      return 301 $scheme://www.mysite1.com$request_uri;
    }
server {
      server_name    www.mysite1.com;
      root            /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/mysite1;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
server {
  server_name mysite2.com;
  return 301 $scheme://www.mysite2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name    www.mysite2.com;
  root           /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/mysite2;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite2/;
  }
}
```

Please, direct me.

Comment: I remember a similar issue like this before, try rewriting the location in the second case and prepend `/mysite2` then proxypass it to just `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: And what's the actual issue ? Why don't you proxy_pass to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1` in the first case ?

Comment: @XavierLucas I confiured web.xml as mysite1 is a default project. for this reason 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'

Comment: @egemen Then it won't work, you must set the context path to /mysite1 in server.xml because otherwise site2 will be available from site1.

Comment: @XavierLucas ok, I did. However <c:url value="xyz.css" />  seems mysite1/xyz.css so it doesnot find css file. How can solve this problem?

Comment: @egemen What do you mean? Don't you want to serve static files from nginx directly instead of serving them through tomcat ?